# How to configure apache2 subdomains to route to different servers

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am running apache 2.4.7 and presently all my traffic is going to a backend server on 8080 on the same server/instance.

I want my www traffic to go to a new server/instance and all my other subdomains (app, api, etc.) to go to the existing 8080.

Can somebody provide some direction?

Help appreciated.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
 ServerName example.com
 Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
 ServerAlias www.example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/
 Redirect "/ft/" "/"
 ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
 ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do an external redirect to the new server for the `www` subdomain, you'll need to add the following to your configuration, under the other rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/${REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And you would need to remove the `ServerAlias` directive. This is also assuming you've already pointed DNS to the new host.

---

If the new box serving the `www` content is to be another backed server, you would need another virtual host. Add the following at the top instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ProxyPass / http://other-box/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://other-box/
</VirtualHost>
```

And you still would need to remove the `ServerAlias` directive.